# Rails Tutorial ch.10 ex 2 - undefined method `activated?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am working on the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl (3rd edition) exercise 2

It consists of two parts, and the second part raises an error:

> Explanation: A user wants to access an other user's profile page. When this account is not yet activated the user that wanted to access, gets redirected to the root page (easy right?)

The code that I know should do this job:

```
(app/controllers/users_controller.rb)
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
end
```

There are three other controller files where I have used the `activated?` method, without any errors whatsoever. But in this occassion I get an error when visiting the unactivated user's page.

This is output from the console:

```
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"101"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?     
LIMIT 1  [["id", 101]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `activated?' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `show'
```

What causes the error? The user is in the database only not activated yet (activated = false).

EDIT:

Found the problem that causes the error. I have made several accounts, which I also deleted. That worked, but the id's keeps counting up from the last one I deleted. so the next user wasn't under 101 it was under 107. Reset the database and now it works. thanks sajinmp for letting me look at the database again.

The problem with the id's is still persisting but I will create another thread for that, because it has nothing to do with this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is pretty verbose. Please reduce it to be more concise about your specific question. Please read "[ask]" including the last link, and "[mcve]".

Comment: The error is something related to the database. The fetch returns an internal server error. So you didnt get the user. Need more details. What is `User.find(101)` producing in rails console?

Comment: Much improved wording for the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tell you `undefined method 'activated?' for nil:NilClass`. This basically means that you call `activated?` on `nil`. It seems like the line before didn't find an user. Furthermore you said that `User.find(params[:id])` also raised an error before. This is was `find` should do when it does not find an entry.

You need to find out why there is no user with an `id=101` in your database. Did you delete that user? Do you pass an invalid value to that method? How do you generate the link to that method?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is with the first line, where the user is not found apparently. There are now 101 users in the database. The only difference with the last one is the column activated, which is set to false at this point.

But its still in the database, so what causes the error that the user is not found?